# put_records() only accepts keyword arguments in Kinesis boto3 Python API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import json
import decimal

#kinesis = boto3.resource('kinesis', region_name='eu-west-1')
client = boto3.client('kinesis')
with open("questions.json") as json_file:
    questions = json.load(json_file)
    Records = []
    count = 0
    for question in questions:
        value1 = question['value']
        if value1 is None:
            value1 = '0'
        record = { 'StreamName':'LoadtestKinesis', 'Data':b'question','PartitionKey':'value1' }
        Records.append(record)
        count +=1
        if count == 500:
            response = client.put_records(Records)
            Records = []
```

This is my python script to load a array of json files to *kinesis stream* where I am combining 500 records to use `put_records` function . But I am getting an error: `put_records() only accepts keyword arguments` . How do I pass a **list** of Records to this method? Each record is a **json** with a partition key .

Sample Json :

```
[{
        "air_date": "2004-12-31",
        "answer": "FDDDe",
        "category": "AACC",
        "question": "'No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds, Giants & Braves'",
        "round": "DDSSS!",
        "show_number": "233",
        "value": "$200"
    }]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
    import boto3
    import json
    import decimal
    import time


    def putdatatokinesis(RecordKinesis):
        start = time.clock()
        response = client.put_records(Records=RecordKinesis, StreamName='LoadtestKinesis')
        print ("Time taken to process" +  len(Records) + " is " +time.clock() - start)
        return response
client = boto3.client('kinesis')
firehoseclient = boto3.client('firehose')
with open("questions.json") as json_file:
    questions = json.load(json_file)
    Records = []
    RecordKinesis = []
    count = 0
    for question in questions:
        value1 = question['value']
        if value1 is None:
            value1 = '0'
        recordkinesis = { 'Data':b'question','PartitionKey':value1 }
        RecordKinesis.append(recordkinesis)
        Records.append(record)
        count +=1
        if count == 500:
            putdatatokinesis(RecordKinesis)
            Records = []
            RecordKinesis = []
```

This worked , The idea is to pass the argument Records as a keyed argument .

Answer (score 1):

When passing multiple records, you need to encapsulate the records in a list of records, and then add the stream identifier.

Format is like so:

```
{
   "Records": [ 
      { 
         "Data": blob,
         "ExplicitHashKey": "string",
         "PartitionKey": "string"
      },
      {
         "Data": "another record",
         "ExplicitHashKey": "string",
         "PartitionKey": "string"
      }
   ],
   "StreamName": "string"
}
```

See the [Kinesis docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) for more info.

Comment: What if I have millions of records , i cannot write each data manually in Records ? 
I was looking to loop in and add each record in the list . Kinesis has a best performance at 500 records per batch , so I need a way to append 500 records at once

Comment: @AnshumanRanjanyou can still do batch record processing. You just need to slightly modify your code.