# Python Lambda function to capture AWS cloud watch logs of AWS MQ and send to kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-mq

I got an Python script from [put_records() only accepts keyword arguments in Kinesis boto3 Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484987/put-records-only-accepts-keyword-arguments-in-kinesis-boto3-python-api) which will load json files to kinesis stream.

[My architecture is something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcjHo.png)

In AWS console, I have created a Lambda function with the above code added to it.[Lambda Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r4pz.png)

How will I integrate or tell my lambda function that it wakes up every one minute. Should I need to add the capture messages via Cloud-watch events. If so how..?

I did get this solution form below link.

Python Script:-

```
import time
import boto3
import stomp

kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis')


class Listener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)
        kinesis_client.put_record(
            StreamName='inter-lambda',
            Data=u'{}\r\n'.format(message).encode('utf-8'),
            PartitionKey='0'
        )


def handler(event, context):
    conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[('localhost', 61616)])
    conn.set_listener('', Listener(conn))
    conn.start()
    conn.connect(login='user', passcode='pass')
    conn.subscribe(destination='A.B.C.D', ack='auto')
    print('Waiting for messages...')
    time.sleep(10)
    conn.close()
    return ''
```

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazonmq-invoke-aws-lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [schedule Lambda functions to run using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).

Another alternative may be to [subscribe to the log events and deliver them to Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html).

Comment: Thank you..! But how will my Lambda function captures incoming MQ messages and send back to Kinesis